# create a file name with other languages in php

Tags: php, mysql, file

I am having Table "language" in My DB. I want To Create The File Name By Using Values Of the Language Field(Like தமிழ்.txt,lə fʁ̥ɒ̃sɛ.txt).

For Example : 
1 => தமிழ், 
2 => lə fʁ̥ɒ̃sɛ

```
$con = mysql_connect('host', 'uname', 'password');
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $con);
mysql_select_db("city", $con);
$sql="SELECT LAnguage FROM detail";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$fileName = $row['LAnguage'];      //out put like '\u0ba4\u0bae\u0bbf\u0bb4\u0bcd'
$fp = fopen($fileName.".txt","w+");
fclose($fp);
mysql_close($con);
```

But file create like "à®¤à®®à®¿à®´à¯ .txt"
I need file like தமிழ் .txt

Comment: user standard naming, it's very bad practice to save with other charsets

Comment: that's file. but i need to save some .eml file-name as subject of the mail (for customers sanctification )

Comment: It depends whether the underlying filesystem supports the charset; something you can't always guarantee, and it invariably causes problems - so it's generally considered bad practise

Comment: Do your users actually look at the filesystem itself, or simply look at files through your application; if the latter then you can save the file with whatever simple ASCII name you like (a hash value is often an idea), but store the subject with the filename on your database, and display the subject to users in the appropriate charset

Comment: @GowthamRooster : I think your language of the filename doesn't supported.

Comment: @Mark Baker . i have no idea about the file system concept.(our application running in windows platform ). Can you please elaborate some more . it may be helpful for me